# Input string was not in a correct format using ASP.NET c# web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting error like below:

> "when converting a string to datetime parse the string to take the
>   date before putting each variable into the datetime object"

If the status is duplicate then only I am getting this error and If status is success means data is inserting working fine.

Below is my button code.

```
Admin_DataLogic abl = new Admin_DataLogic();
Admin_BusinessObject abo = new Admin_BusinessObject();
protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Status = string.Empty;
    int Sno = 0;
    abo.Para1 = "News";
    abo.Para2 = txt_Heading.Text;
    abo.Para3 = txt_Postedby.Text;
    abo.Para4 = txt_Location.Text;
    abo.Para8 = txt_SmallDesc.Text;

    abo.Dateused2 = DateTime.Now;
    string Filepath_FileBrowse = abo.Dateused2.ToString("MMddyyyy") + "_" +      FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
    abo.Para9 = Filepath_FileBrowse;

    abo.Dateused = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_EventDate.Text);
  if (ddl_Filemode.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Link")
    {
        abo.Para5 = txt_URL.Text;
        abo.Para6 = "";
       abo.Para7 = "";
        abl.Admin_Insert_AddNews(abo, out Status, out Sno);
        if (Status == "Success")
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath("../images/news_images/New folder/" + abo.Dateused2.ToString("MMddyyyy") + "_" + FileUpload1.FileName));
                System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(MapPath("../images/news_images/New folder/") + abo.Dateused2.ToString("MMddyyyy") + "_" + FileUpload1.FileName);

                System.Drawing.Image bmp1 = img1.GetThumbnailImage(281, 117, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                bmp1.Save(MapPath("../images/news_images/") + abo.Dateused2.ToString("MMddyyyy") + "_" + FileUpload1.FileName);

            }

            lbl_msg.Visible = true;
            lbl_msg.Text = Status;
            Response.Redirect("Thanks.aspx");

        }
    }
     else if (Status == "Duplicate")
        {
            lbl_msg.Visible = true;
            lbl_msg.Text = Status;
        }
```

}

I am getting exception in Data logic and Below is my data logic Code.

```
 public void Admin_Insert_AddNews(Admin_BusinessObject  bo, out string Status, out int Sno)
{
    ConnectMethod();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Admin_Insert_AddNews", con);
    try
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postingtype", bo.Para1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Heading", bo.Para2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postedby", bo.Para3);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", bo.Para4);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDate", bo.Dateused);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attachment", bo.Para5);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", bo.Para6);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attachmentid", bo.Para7);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SmallDesc", bo.Para8);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", bo.Para9);
        SqlParameter outputstatus = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        outputstatus.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        SqlParameter sqlparam2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sno", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlparam2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Status = outputstatus.Value.ToString().Trim();
        Sno = int.Parse(sqlparam2.Value.ToString());

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Status = ex.Message.ToString();
        Sno = 0;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();

    }
}
```

Comment: At which line you are getting error?

Comment: I am getting exception in Data logic after this line:  Sno = int.Parse(sqlparam2.Value.ToString()); . @NiranjanKala

Comment: What is the value of "sqlparam2.Value?

Comment: Have you checked the value of sqlparam2.. It may possible that It has some incorrect value e.g. string.Empty or "", but your question related to some datetime conversion

Comment: `AddWithValue` is often a bad choice try `Add(name, dbType).Value = your value` and you will get better results though that might have nothing to do with your issue

Comment: you expect the stored procedure that you are calling to always return a value (a valid datetime value). So it would be better you share the code of the stored procedure with us. The code above doesn't show why the stored procedure would not return the value you expect.

Comment: With out more detail its hard to be sure what's causing the issue but my suspicion is that its `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDate", bo.Dateused);` as that clearly is date related, check that Dateused is a date or if not convert it to one before setting the value, also check for nulls remember c# null != DBNull.Value

Comment: replace your this line : `Sno = int.Parse(sqlparam2.Value.ToString());` with `int.TryParse(sqlparam2.Value.ToString(), Sno);`

Comment: Sno value  is shwoing 0. @NiranjanKala

Comment: yes if `sqlparam2.Value` this value goes empty it will set 0 by default.

Comment: So what I have to do. @SunilKumar

Comment: is your value empty ?

Comment: Sno = int.Parse(sqlparam2.Value.ToString()); when I debug and mouse over Sno then showing zero value and still confused. @SunilKumar

Comment: what value you are getting in  `sqlparam2.Value` ?

Comment: Nothing is showing in sqlparam2.value. @SunilKumar

Comment: Ok then it will converted to automatically in 0

Comment: what you want exactly when `sqlparam2.Value` this value is empty ?

Comment: Yes value is empty. @SunilKumar

Comment: then what value you are expecting in `Sno` ?

Comment: Nothing If record is duplicate nothing should come into Sno. @SunilKumar

Comment: but in your catch block you set : `Sno = 0;` ? is it ok ?
and you want `Sno` as a `null` when `sqlparam2.Value` this value is empty, am I right ?

Comment: No Sno is output parameter from my stored procedure. @SunilKumar

Comment: ok you want Sno as null when sqlparam2.value is empty ?

Comment: and return null value ?

Comment: The code in the top block is invalid, does not compile. Please correct and update post, the location of the missing '}' is important for a valid answer, as is it could be your issue.

Comment: Ya Thank you very much and I set into stored procedure values is duplicate(count>0) then output parameter value as set @sno=0 and I got answer from your help thank you very much once again. @SunilKumar